# Problem turning HTTP Chunking off in AXIS2

Tags: apache-axis, transfer-encoding, chunked-encoding

I have a client sending me requests without HTTP chunking (they use content-length).  When my server responds, chunking is enabled, and the client can't handle this -  even though they should be able to as they are using HTTP 1.1.....

I have tried to disable chunking by removing the entry below from the axis2 config file (axis2.xml) but the response is still going back chunked.

chunked

So the question is, is there somewhere else that the chunking is being enabled that is over-riding the axis2 setting?  In tomcat setting perhaps?

Webserver details - tomcat 6.0.16, axis2 2.1.3

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 5):

you can disable Chunking programatically as follows:

Options options = new Options();
[...]
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");

Source: http://jcesarperez.blogspot.com/2008/10/resolviendo-problemas-de.html

Answer (score 2):

If you created a stub for your web service, just do this:

`myStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);`